# Live update of number of notifications without refresh and without any click using AJAX & PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**Hello Devs !**

I am working on a notification system.
What i am doing is that I need to give notifications for the customer without any refresh, and without any click. But I am confused.

What I did is :

1. Using ajax and php, whenever a product's discount is inserted or updated, a notification is inserted in the notifications table in the database. And this is working properly.
2. Then, I've did an ajax function containing a GET method with a getNotif.php file, that SELECTS the notifications' text and the notifications number for the certain customer and appends them into the HTML by sending them from the PHP to the AJAX by get response.
3. Till now, I need to refresh in order to change the notif number when an update is set, or even to see the new notification also. Since I didn't make an event handler like onclick or onchange. (because there is no a certain click that I need, what I need is to update the notification without any action from the customer..)

**How does this happen ?**

My PHP File :

```
<?php
require("../include/dbconn.php");
session_start();
$uname=$_SESSION['uname'];
$customerID=$_SESSION['customerID'];
$notif="";
$unreadNotif=0;
if(isset($_GET['getNotif'])){
$query = "SELECT notification_date,notification_status,products.product_id,product_title,product_picture,store_name,discount_percent
 FROM notification,products,stores,customer,favorite_list WHERE products.product_id=notification.product_id
 AND products.store_id=stores.store_id AND customer.customer_id=favorite_list.customer_id AND stores.store_id=favorite_list.store_id
 AND customer.customer_id='$customerID' AND product_active=1 AND notification_status!=-1 ORDER BY notification_date DESC";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $notif_date=$row['notification_date'];
      $product_title=$row['product_title'];
      $product_picture=$row['product_picture'];
      $store_name=$row['store_name'];
      $discount_percent=$row['discount_percent'];
      $notif_status=$row['notification_status'];

      $notif.= "<li class=\"notification-box\">
        <div class=\"row\">
          <div class=\"col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-3 text-center\">
            <img src=\"../img/products/$product_picture\" class=\"\" style=\"width:80px;height:auto\">
          </div>
          <div class=\"col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-8\">
            <strong class=\"text-info\">$store_name</strong>
            <div>
              Exclusive Now! $discount_percent% discount on $product_title
            </div>
            <small class=\"text-warning\">$notif_date</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li><hr>";
  }


$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(notification_id) as unreadNotif
 FROM notification,products,stores,customer,favorite_list WHERE products.product_id=notification.product_id
 AND products.store_id=stores.store_id AND customer.customer_id=favorite_list.customer_id AND stores.store_id=favorite_list.store_id
 AND customer.customer_id='$customerID' AND product_active=1 AND notification_status=0  GROUP BY customer.customer_id";
$result2 = mysqli_query($db, $query2);
$arr=mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$unreadNotif=$arr['unreadNotif'];

}

else{
  $notif="<span>No Notifications Right Now.</span>";
}


$data = array(
   'notif' => $notif,
   'unread_notif'  => $unreadNotif
);

echo json_encode($data);
}

else{
  echo "error";

}

 ?>
```

My JS File :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    function getNotif(){
      var getNotif="";

    $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "../phpOnly/getNotif.php",
         data: {getNotif:getNotif},
         dataType:"json",
         success: function(data) {
              // alert(data.notif);
              document.getElementById("insideNotif").innerHTML=data.notif;
              // alert(document.getElementsByClassName("insideNotif").innerHTML);
              $(".unreadNotif").html(data.unread_notif);
              }



          });

}
getNotif();

});
```

My HTML PART :

```
<div class="insideNotif" id="insideNotif">

</div>
```

**NOTE:** I know I must prevent SQL INJECTIONS by prepared statements. Neglect this for now. And thanks for your time :)

Comment: you can call `getNotif()` under success function of ajax.i.e: whenever you do  update or insert that should work.

Comment: it didn't work, it still needs refreshing the page. why?

Comment: It worked Now! Thanks alot man !
I used : `setTimeout(getNotifFn, 5000);` in the success fn of ajax

Comment: you can see my note in the post @Dharman